# I am unable to delete a database in mysql ending in pound '#'

Tags: mysql

I created a database xyz# in MySQL accidentally when I was trying to create xyz. Now when I try to drop it, I get to the next line. I searched online but no luck. I tried escape characters / \ and single and double quote to consider # name of the database but no luck.
Any idea how to delete a database ending with #. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
DROP DATABASE `dbnameendingin#`
```

Comment: Use backticks not single quote :)